# Getting child elements using cssSelector

Tags: xpath, css-selectors, protractor, cucumberjs

I have a code segment that looks like this

```
<div class="class1">
    <div class="ng-scope"> apple </div>
    <div class="ng-scope"> butter </div>
```

I want to get the text of the children. I do not want to use ng-scope since that is not a unique identifiter, but class1 is. How can I do something like identifying the parent, so ('.class1') or using xpath, and then getting the text from all its children. so the print out would look something like

```
" [ apple, butter ]; "
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$$('.class1 div').getText().then(function(values) {
  // This is an array containing ['apple', 'butter']
});
```

Comment: so easy and useful. Thank you my friend.